# Mongoose.Create is not sending assigned value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

**Update:** (The answer below was correct and helped to change the code, the issue now lies with mongoose and mongoDB, where mongoose appears to attempt a writing creating the collection but not actually writing the documents)

Why can't I bind the item that is nested in the req.body.goe.coordinates.0 or .1  The req.body.geo.coordinates is showing as an object which has an array of two numbers (coordinates). So far I can get the server to write all the other fields accept the geo field.

I assumed i could use req.body.geo.coordinates.0 because zero would be the first number in the array, right? i must be thinking of the req.body incorrectly and trying to access it in a manner that isn't correct.

How can I access these coordinates so that I can place them in the correct spot in the mongoose schema. I tried loading it as a whole object but mongoose wouldn't write that geo portion and would use the default.

As always thank you for you responses.

relevant part of mongoose schema:

```
var itemsSchema = new Schema({item:{
user_name: {type: String, default: 'badboy for life'},
city: {type:String},
geo:{
    gtype: {type:String, default: "Point"},         
    coordinates: {longitude: {type:Number, default: -97.740678},  
               latitude: {type:Number, default: 30.274026 }},
},
title: {type: String, match: /[a-z]/},
desc: {type:String},
cost:{type: Number, index: true},

//Still can't get the image to load into mongoose correctly I'm assuming 
//   i'm doing it wrong but that's a question for another day.
//image: {                            
//  mime:  {type:String},
//  bin: Buffer,
//  }

}});
```

Express app.post that handles the post to the mongoDB server. It currently spits out the default values.

```
 app.post('/js/dish', parser, function(req, res) {

        var a = req.body.user_name;
        var b = req.body.title;
        var c = req.body.cost;
        var d = req.body.ingdts;
        var e = req.body.location;
        var f = req.body.geo.coordinates.0;
        var g = req.body.geo.coordinates.1;

        // create an object, information comes from AJAX request from Angular

    console.log(req.body.geo["coordinates"]);
    console.log("hey the object request has this in it: "+ req, req.method);

        Item.create({"item.user_name":a, "item.title": b, "item.cost": c, "item.desc": d, "item.city": e, "item.geo.coordinates.latitude":f,"item.geo.coordinates.longitude":g},

         function(err, item) {
            if (err){
                res.send(err);
            }else{
                // get and return all the items after you create another
                getItems(res);
            }

        });
```

Map Service in Angular which gets and Sets GPS

```
(function(){

var mapSrvc = angular.module("mapService",[]);
console.log('map factory baby!')
  var position = [];
  var mapPopulation = [];

    mapSrvc.service('Maping',['$http',function(){
        return{
            getUserGPS:function(){
            return position;
            },
        setUserGPS:function(lat,long){
            return position = [lat,long];
            },
        getMapPop:function(dbLocs){
            return mapPopulation = dbLocs;
            }
        }
    }])

})();
```

The Angular control which is setting the value and sending it to the express portion of the app

```
    $scope.createItem = function(item){
    if($scope.items.text != false){
      var itemCord = Maping.getUserGPS();
        $scope.items={
            user_name: item.user_name,
            title: item.title,
            cost: item.cost,
            location: item.location,
            ingdts: item.ingdts,
            geo:{coordinates:{longitude:itemCord[1],latitude:itemCord[0]}}
            }
        console.log("breadcrumb to see if item was defined: ",$scope.items)

        $scope.loading = true;

        Items.create($scope.items)

        .success(function(data){
            Items.get()
            .success(function(data){
            $scope.items= data;
            $scope.loading = false;
            console.log(data);
        })

        .error(function(err){
          console.log('Error: ' + err);
        });
            $scope.loading=false;
            $scope.items= {};
            $scope.items= data;
            })
            .error(function(err){
                console.log('Error: ' + err);
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: @Jking thanks for the help I've been able to narrow down the issue I think, It's actually something between mongoose and mongoDB. I've been doing things in mongodb to see if mongoose is even attempting to write which it is, so it might be a restriction from mongoDB. I may update the post if the answer arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coordinates object in your schema is an object literal, not an array.

Array elements can be accessed by index, but not in the way you assumed. In an array, you'd access elements with bracket notation so consider the following:

```
var foo = ["bar", "baz"];
console.log(foo[0]);
```

For an object however, unless you're actually grabbing keys named 0 and 1, it doesn't work in the same way.

If you want to access `longitude` and `latitude` in the bracket notation above, the coordinates object in your Schema would have to be an array. Although, that kind of makes naming the values and putting them in the `longitude` and `latitude` objects kind of useless. Talking about this part here (I took out the comment to make it easier to follow):

```
 coordinates: {longitude: {type:Number, default: -97.740678}, latitude: {type:Number, default: 30.274026 }},
```

You have another option which may be more suitable. Just access the values in the coordinates object by key. Do you know how object literals work in JavaScript? Instead of accessing values by number (or *index*) you access them by the names you gave them (or the *keys*). So you'd instead access the values like this:

```
var f = req.body.geo.coordinates.longitude;
var g = req.body.geo.coordinates.latitude;
```

... because that's what you named them.

To simply things, to access by index, either name the keys 0 and 1 instead of longitude and latitude in the coordinates object (you probably should not do this) or make the coordinates object into an array like in the above example with `foo`, or access the keys by the names that you gave them like that directly above.

Comment: I swtiched the array to be an object with a key and value pair. I can see based on my console.log that it is creating a sub object called geo with a sub obeject called coordinates. but for some reason express isn't passing the objects to the mongoDB. could it be because the object is to large?

Comment: What array are you talking about? And can you paste what prints when you run `console.log(req.body.geo["coordinates"]);`?

Comment: sorry, I didn't include the Angular Service which is setting and getting the Array that I was talking about. The Angular service creates an array which is called on when the user allows GPS (setting), I then call the position which was set from my item controller, and store it in `var itemCord` (making that var an array, correct?). I then pass `itemCord[1]`, and `itemCord[0]` to set longitude and latitude in `$scope.items{...}` I then pass the entire JSON object to create which sends it to the express portion and then that were it isn't setting it correctly to the mongoose schema.

Comment: Ok can you still show me the console.log from my other comment?

Comment: `{longitude:-97.476087, latitude: 30.720462}`

I see that it's set differently than the default so it has the new coordinates

Comment: Ok yea. What I'm saying is that you have to access longitude and latitude by name like in my answer. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: yes i do. I updated my code it to be `item.geo.coordinates.longitude` and the other is `item.geo.coordinates.latitude`. I restarted the server after the update since that was on the Express portion and it still doesn't want to send it to the database. the db is running and it has previous documents from before this iteration of adding geo. Not sure what has changed to make this break the communication to the db. I should add that I have another collection of users which writes and reads just fine, so I know it's set up correctly.

Comment: Hey Thanks so much for continuring to help. 

could this be the issues, from MongoDB docs:

Fields with 2dsphere Indexes can only hold Geometries

    Fields with 2dsphere indexes must hold geometry data in the form of coordinate pairs or GeoJSON data. If you attempt to insert a document with non-geometry data in a 2dsphere indexed field, or build a 2dsphere index on a collection where the indexed field has non-geometry data, the operation will fail.

See also

The unique indexes limit in Sharding Operational Restrictions.

Comment: It doesn't look like you specified in the Schema to make you coordinates 2dsphere indexes. Check the LocationSchema in this post: http://blog.robertonodi.me/how-to-use-geospatial-indexing-in-mongodb-using-express-and-mongoose/. That looks like what you need. In this case you'd setup the loc object with a type of a number array.

Comment: I'll take a look at it and see if that solves the problem. I'll fiddle with it through out the day and will get back to you.

Comment: Yea, I didn't realize the problem went deeper than the object vs array thing. Sorry about that.